# Google analytics, display more than 1 query

Tags: php, html, google-analytics

I'm pretty new to PHP so bear with me please :)

Right so I am working with google analytics and I am using one of their scripts to display one query. It looks all good but I'm not really sure how to display more?

I know to get a query, but I have trouble displaying it. I can only display 1. 
I only have sessions but I want to add more for example , bounce rate etc.

Here is the code I am using:

```html
  <?php

require_once 'google-client/vendor/autoload.php';


  session_start();


  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAuthConfig('google-client/src/Google/client_secret.json');
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);


  if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);


    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);


    $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

    $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
    printResults($results);
  } else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/acp/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  }


  function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {

    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
      $items = $accounts->getItems();
      $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();


      $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
          ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

      if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $properties->getItems();
        $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();


        $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
            ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

        if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
          $items = $profiles->getItems();


          return $items[0]->getId();

        } else {
          throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
        }
      } else {
        throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
    }
  }

  function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {

    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
        'ga:146790870',
        '2016-11-01',
        'today',
        'ga:sessions');

   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
      'ga:146790870',
      '2016-11-01',
      'today',
      'ga:percentNewSessions');
  }
  function printResults($results) {

    if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {


      $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();


      $rows = $results->getRows();
      $sessionstotal = $rows[0][0];


      // Print the results.
      print "<div class='col s12 m6 l3' style='text-align:center;'>
      <div class='card green '>
            <div class='card-content white-text'>
              <span class='card-title'>Total Sessions</span>
              <p style='font-size: 1.8rem; font-weight: bold;'>$sessionstotal</p>
            </div>
            <div class='card-action  green darken-2'>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>";
    } else {
      print "<p>No results found.</p>";
    }
  }
  ?>
```

If someone can give me any tips on how to improve it, or what to do please help me:) Please bear in mind I have very limited knowledge on PHP as I'm learning it while doing projects.

thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear if you need to make multiple queries or if you simply need to add more metrics to your existing query. For example you can query for `ga:sessions` and `ga:percentNewSessions` in the same query.

```
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:146790870',
    '2016-11-01',
    'today',
    'ga:sessions, percentNewSessions');
```

Then you would need to extract the second metric from the results:

```
  $rows = $results->getRows();
  $sessionstotal = $rows[0][0];
  $percentNewSessions = $rows[0][1];


  // Print the results.
  print "<div class='col s12 m6 l3' style='text-align:center;'>
  <div class='card green '>
        <div class='card-content white-text'>
          <span class='card-title'>Total Sessions</span>
          <p style='font-size: 1.8rem; font-weight: bold;'>$sessionstotal</p>
          <span class='card-title'>Percent New Sessions</span>
          <p style='font-size: 1.8rem; font-weight:bold;'>$percentNewSessions</p>
        </div>
        <div class='card-action  green darken-2'>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>";
```

Play around with the results object until you get a sense of its structure. Always use the [Reference docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) to understand what fields are available.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked, I cant believe it was that easy ngl, kinda brain-farted tbh coz that is a very simple fix. But thanks dude!